# ESRI layer files to directed graph?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, layers, graph

I am pretty new to ArcGIS and would like to extract GPS coordinates of nodes as well as the length of all edges connecting those nodes from some ESRI layer files (http://www.nyc.gov/html/dcp/html/bytes/dwnlion.shtml).

Ideally, I would like to store all this in a csv file where each line would be:

GPS coordinates node A, GPS coordinates node B, length of edge connecting A and B.

provided the direction of traffic on the edge connecting A to B allows one to drive from A to B.  If the edge is a two-way street, we would also have a line in the csv file that would read:

GPS coordinates node B, GPS coordinates node A, length of edge connecting A and B.

In the layer files, there is information on street direction, nodes and segments but I have no idea how I could produce the csv file described above.

Comment: Please **edit the question** to specify which data layer you are using (none of them appear to be GPS-related).  It is important to note that "layer files", in ArcGIS parlance, do not contain data -- they are just drawing rules which reference a data source.  Therefore, you really want the data out of the file geodatabase feature class, not the layer file.  You should also specify what programming environment you want to use, since the answer is very different in Python, VB.Net, C#, and Java.

Comment: your new to ArcGIS should be on your profile not your question.

Comment: I think in this case 'node' is being used ambiguously, you mean points perhaps, not ArcInfo nodes. More info is needed on what is actually in the layer files (as @Vince indicated correctly don't contain information, just links). You're talking about GPS which to me means a string of points which can be converted into a linestring (A-B-C-D...) but what you need is 2-point lines A-B, B-C, C-D and so on to do these calculations. To get from where you are to what you want would involve a bit of coding (not too much)... how do you feel about learning some python (already installed with ArcGis).

Answer (score 3):

There is a standard already there called ArcInfo ungenerate(export).

Using the ArcInfo generate(import) and ungenerate command.

But there are many other technologies doing the same thing now such as json, landxml, esrixml workspace document and many others I can't even keep up with.

ETGeowizards contains a tool to create the ungenerate file. go to [ET GeoWizards](http://www.ian-ko.com/ET_GeoWizards/gw_NoRestrictions.htm) to see the free to use functions and the format which sounds like it would closely match what you want.

Comment: UNGENERATE won't provide the requested information (which is incomplete -- the OP will also need the node ids, as in `nodeAid|nodeAx,nodeAy|nodeBid|nodeBx,nodeBy|segAB.length` )